# Tables getting locked in oracle database

Tags: oracle, session, locking, database-administration

I understand that some sessions like insert or delete queries lock the table and we should wait until that session ends to run another alter query on the table.
We usually face 'resource busy' error at this times.
But sometimes even though the session has been ended and it's status has been changed to 'INACTIVE', this session remains and locks the table and our solution will be to just kill it and set the table free for further actions.
My question is why this happens? I mean why does a normal altering session becomes a lock and remains until we kill it?
Is there anyway for us to prevent this problem?
I hope the explanation was clear.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Presumably, the blocking session has not issued a commit or rollback, so the transaction is still active.

Comment: The session being 'inactive', does not mean it ended, nor that the transaction it initiated is committed or rolled back. And as long as the transaction is active, the lock will remain held and block the ddls.